# Why does my string sanitizer cause a 403 Access Denied error?

Tags: php, sql

So, having just written some database scripts, I've just secured them by making sure strings are sanitized before they're sent to the database (i.e. quote marks, `\r`, `\n`, `\0` and `NULL` are removed). I just tried to break it with an SQL injection. However, instead of what I expected it to do (i.e. register a user with the sanitized SQL command username), it threw a 403.

---

- Tried to register.

  ```
  Username: idfx"; DELETE * FROM tests WHERE uname='me'
  Password: xxxx                      (not blanked, that's what I used)
  Confirm: xxxx
  Email: x@x.co                       (random and made up)
  ```
- Those details get run through this function:

  ```
  function cleanString($string) {
      $string = str_replace("\0", " ", $string); // NULL char: ASCII 0, \0
      $string = str_replace("\r", " ", $string); // CR carriage return: \r
      $string = str_replace("\n", " ", $string); // LF line feed: \n
      $string = str_replace("\"", " ", $string); // " quote: \"
      $string = str_replace("\'", " ", $string); // ' quote: \'
      $string = str_replace(chr(26), " ", $string); // Ctrl-Z: ASCII 26, chr(26)
      return $string;
  }
  ```
- I would expect (but couldn't check) that the following string of Username would be returned:

  ```
  idfx ; DELETE * FROM tests WHERE uname= me
  ```
- My database script then takes this string, commits it to the database (this script is working fine). I would expect it, therefore, to show my successful registration page and a new entry created in the user details table in the database. It did neither, instead throwing a 403 Access Denied, to a file normally accessible to all.

---

Now while I'm not concerned about this behaviour from a security POV, it is a little confusing. Is is possibly because the SQL syntax is wrong? I don't use deletion much at all; have I got the statement wrong? Or is something else strange going on?

---

EDIT (problem solved): The 403 was, indeed, caused by faulty SQL syntax in the `DELETE` statement. However, on fixing that I instead got a fatal error, stating that I was trying to call a member function on a non-object (because the function that would return the object returned `false` instead, because of another faulty SQL statement). This other faulty statement was caused by the string sanitizer not replacing `'` characters, so I removed the escape backslash in the `\'` and it now works fine.

Comment: *"have I got the statement wrong?"* - It is (*wrong*). Your SQL is incorrect. `DELETE *` remove the `*`. The syntax for `DELETE` is `DELETE FROM table`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: Ah yep, so it is. However, now I get a fatal error :)

Comment: What's the full error message?

Comment: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/u875642593/public_html/register/action.php on line 30. Clearly, that means the function that is returning what should be a MySQL result set is returning `false` instead, which happens when either the connection fails or the SQL query is bad.

Comment: Yep, something failed. You'll need to edit your question with the code you're actually using.